# How can i increase reducers in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
select
    emp.deptno, emp.ename, emp.empno, emp.job, emp.mgr,
    emp.mgr, emp.hiredate, emp.sal, emp.comm, dept.dname,
    dept.loc
from emp
join dept on from emp.deptno = dept.deptno;
```

IT is 9GB data.it is giving problem at reducer.its strucking at reducer 99%.
I have incresed reducer to 150 but it is not giving result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
    set mapred.reduce.tasks=113
```

And you problem could be related to data skewness (It means some keys are very dense).

Answer (score 0):

A skewed join will send a disproportionately large number of values to only one reducer and you'll get the long tail of a 99% job complete syndrome, so may be experiencing this. Looking at the job logs (IO specially) will reveal if this is the culprit.

In such cases you can use [Skewed Join Optimization](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Skewed+Join+Optimization), which in turn relies on [List Bucketing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/ListBucketing). You will have to determine *which* key values (`depno`) are heavily skewed and declare it accordingly in the DDL:

```
alter table emp (schema) skewed by  (depno) on ('<skewedvalue>');
```

Read the linked article for details, go over the comments and changes of [HIVE-3086](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3086).